# List<> unable to hold the data of database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have a sql table named "Employee". The table has 4 fields: EMPLID,EMPNAME,EMPCONTACT and EMPEMAIL. I am creating a Asp.net MVC application. In my Model, I have a Users class as given below:-

```
Class Users
{
    public string ID{get; set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Contact{get;set;}
    public string Email(get;set;}
}
```

Now Code which will take the data from the database using ado.net and send it to Controller will be given below:-

```
Class DatabaseAccess
{
    public List<Users> GetData()
    {
        List<Users> eachemployee = new List<Users>;
        Users user = new Users();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring);
        con.open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new Sql Data Adapter("Select * From Employee",conn);
        Dataset ds = new dataset();
        adp.fill(ds,"Employee");

        for(int i=0;i<ds.tables[0].rows.count;i++) 
        {
            user.ID = ds.Tables[0].rows[i]["EMPID"].tostring(); 
            user.Name = ds.Tables[0].rows[i]["EMPNAME"].tostring();
            user.Contact = ds.Tables[0].rows[i]["EMPCONTACT"].tostring();
            user.Email = ds.Tables[0].rows[i]["EMPEMAIL"].tostring();
            eachemployee.Add(user);
       }
       return eachemployee;
   }
```

Now the problem is eachemployee always contains the rows with same data. If table has 2 rows as given below:

```
Emp1, Gaurav, 888888888,abc@gmail.com
Emp2, Sharma, 999999999,xyz@gmail.com
```

Then eachemployee list contains 2 rows with the same data. That is both rows consists of Emp2 data as given below:

```
Emp2, Sharma, 999999999,xyz@gmail.com
Emp2, Sharma, 999999999,xyz@gmail.com
```

How can i get out from the above issues? I didn't even know what is the reason for that?

Comment: you're not creating a new `Users` object, but just recycling the same one for each entry in the table. move the Users user = new User() into the loop of the returned data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your

```
Users user = new Users();
```

inside the for loop.

In your code, you are creating only one object, and you are always modifying it and adding it several times to the list...

Comment: Ha. You *just* beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just like

```
for(int i=0;i<ds.tables[0].rows.count;i++){
eachemployee.Add(new User()
  { 
     ID = ds.Tables[0].rows[i]["EMPID"].tostring(),
     Name = ds.Tables[0].rows[i]["EMPNAME"].tostring(),
     Contact = ds.Tables[0].rows[i]["EMPCONTACT"].tostring(),
     Email = ds.Tables[0].rows[i]["EMPEMAIL"].tostring()
  });}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only create one user object and always assign the values to the same object.

```
Users user = new Users();
```

Move this declaration inside your for to create an user object for each row.